# dbcontext loading related entities using select(), include() and where() not working

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, dbcontext

I have the following relationship between the entities.
Company 1 ---* Appointments *---1 Employee

I have the .net asp membership in a separate database. Whenever a user is created it can be assigned to companies, employees, or administrators roles.

in the Index action of my Company Controller, I check the logged in user's role. Based on the role, I make different linq query. For example, administrators can get list of all companies, companies can get list of company which has a username property (string) same as the User.Identity.Name. For both of administrators and companies role, it is working fine.

For the employees role, I want to load all the companies that are related to the current employee. I am having hard time to compose a linq query that does this job.

i tried

```
var companies = db.Companies.Include(c => c.Appointments.Select(a=>a.Employee).Where(e=>e.Username.ToLower() == this.User.Identity.Name.ToLower())).ToList();
```

to which i get this error
"The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path"

Here are the source code,

CompanyController

```
[Authorize]
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    private MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();

    //
    // GET: /Company/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new CompanyIndexViewModel();
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole("administrators")) {
            viewModel = new CompanyIndexViewModel { Companies = db.Companies.ToList() };
        }
        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("companies")) {
            viewModel = new CompanyIndexViewModel { Companies = db.Companies.Where(c => c.Username.ToLower().Equals(this.User.Identity.Name.ToLower())).ToList() };
        }
        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("employees")) {
            var companies = db.Companies.Include(c => c.Appointments.Select(a=>a.Employee).Where(e=>e.Username.ToLower() == this.User.Identity.Name.ToLower())).ToList();
            viewModel = new CompanyIndexViewModel { Companies = companies.ToList() };
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

...

Models

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace TorontoWorkforce.Models
{
    public class Company
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Company Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        [UIHint("PhoneNumber")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        public string Website { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public AddressInfo AddressInfo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

        public Company(){
            this.AddressInfo = new AddressInfo();
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TorontoWorkforce.Models
{
    public class Appointment
    {

        public int AppointmentId { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [UIHint("DateTime")]
        [Display(Name="Appointment Date")]
        public DateTime? DateOfAppointment { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [UIHint("MultilineText")]
        [Display(Name = "Appointment Summary")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Allocated No of Hours")]
        public decimal NoOfHoursWorked { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AppointmentLine> AppointmentLines { get; set; }

        public Appointment() {
            //this.AppointmentLines = new List<AppointmentLine>();
            this.DateOfAppointment = DateTime.Now;
        }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name="Actual No of Hours")]
        public decimal ActualHoursWorked {
            get
            {
                decimal total = 0;
                foreach (var jobline in this.AppointmentLines)
                {
                    total = total + jobline.TimeSpent;
                }
                return total;
            } 
        }


    }

    public class AppointmentLine
    {
        public int AppointmentLineId { get; set; }

        [UIHint("MultilineText")]
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Time Spent")]
        [DataType(DataType.Duration)]
        public decimal TimeSpent { get; set; }

        public int AppointmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TorontoWorkforce.Models
{
    public class Employee: TorontoWorkforce.Models.Person
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Date Hired")]
        public DateTime? DateHired { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Position { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

        public Employee() {
            this.DateHired = DateTime.Now;        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get companies which have appointment with selected employee you don't need to use `Include`. Include is for instructing EF to load all appointments related to the company (and [it doesn't support filtering](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method)). Try this:

```
string userName = this.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
var companies = db.Companies.Where(c => c.Appointments.Any(a => 
                   a.Employee.Username.ToLower() == userName)).ToList();
```

Comment: alternative fix possible  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have an end parentheses in the wrong place. You need one more after "a => a.Employee" and one less after "this.User.Identity.Name.ToLower()));"

Try this code:

```
var companies = db.Companies.Include(c => c.Appointments.Select(a=>a.Employee)).Where(e=>e.Username.ToLower() == this.User.Identity.Name.ToLower()).ToList();
```

Edit:
You should also be able to use the standard string include method:

```
var companies = db.Companies.Include("Appointments.Employee").Where(e=>e.Username.ToLower() == this.User.Identity.Name.ToLower()).ToList();
```

Comment: It did not work.
It throws ArgumentException.The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path

Comment: Interesting. The parentheses was for sure in the wrong place. Have you tried to just use the old string include method?  Something like: db.Companies.Include("Appointments.Employee").Where(e=>e.Username.ToLower() == this.User.Identity.Name.ToLower()).ToList();  See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks @boolean operation ...that statement might work but i am limited by my liniq knowledge.
db.Companies.Include("Appointments.Employee") gives me Company Objects so the Where method doesn't have employee. e=>e.Username... becomes an instance of Company. c=>c.Appointments.Employee???? I think I am back to where I started. ie Company object.

Comment: The relationship between the entities are like so..

Company to Appointment: One to Many
Employee to Appointment: One to Many

I need to get Company or Companies which is related to Appointments which in turn is/are related to the Employee with certain Username.