# Linq Issue dealing with null values in select

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following entities in my solution

```
public class UtilityAccount : IObjectWithState 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UtilityAccountID { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public Guid PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public string ForeignID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Utility> Utilities { get; set; }

    public UtilityAccount()
    {
        Utilities = new List<Utility>();
    }
}

public class Utility : IObjectWithState 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UtilityID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UtilityAccount")]
    public Guid UtilityAccountID { get; set; }
    public virtual UtilityAccount UtilityAccount { get; set; }
    public Guid? ServiceAddressID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ServiceAddressID")]
    public virtual Address ServiceAddress { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
    public double CurrentBalance { get; set; }
    public double? PendingPaymentTotal { get; set; }
    public string ForeignID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UtilityType")]
    public Guid UtilityTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual UtilityType UtilityType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UtilityBill> UtilityBills { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IncomingUtilityPayment> IncomingPayments { get; set; }

    public Utility()
    {
        UtilityBills = new List<UtilityBill>();
        IncomingPayments = new List<IncomingUtilityPayment>();
    }
}

public class IncomingUtilityPayment : IObjectWithState
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid IncomingPaymentID { get; set; }
    public string ForeignID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Utility")]
    public Guid UtilityID { get; set; }
    public virtual Utility Utility { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; } 

    public IncomingPaymentStatus IncomingPaymentStatus { get; set; }
    public double? UtilityAmount { get; set; }
    public double? ConvenienceFee { get; set; }
    public double? TotalAmount { get; set; }

    public string AuthCode { get; set; }
    public string AuthReference { get; set; }
    public string TenderType { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PaymentIdent { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that I am trying to use Linq to retrieve information about a UtilityAccount and I am running into issues with the IncomingPayments for a Utility.  Below is the select statement I am trying to use.

```
returnVal = repo.AllIncluding(o => o.Person, o => o.Utilities, o => o.Utilities.Select(p => p.UtilityType), o => o.Person.BillingAddress, o => o.Utilities.Select(p => p.ServiceAddress), o => o.Utilities.Select(p => p.IncomingPayments.Where(q => q.IncomingPaymentStatus == IncomingPaymentStatus.Pending || q.IncomingPaymentStatus == IncomingPaymentStatus.Processed )));
```

Everything ran fine until I added this clause to the statement.

```
o => o.Utilities.Select(p => p.IncomingPayments.Where(q => q.IncomingPaymentStatus == IncomingPaymentStatus.Pending || q.IncomingPaymentStatus == IncomingPaymentStatus.Processed ))
```

I think my issue ends up being something I am writing wrong in my Linq clause.  The error I am getting is

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
```

Parameter name: path

I can use the following statement with no issues

```
o => o.Utilities.Select(p => p.IncomingPayments)
```

as soon as I add the where clause in I get the error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EntityFramework nor linq-to-entities, but if it's just like linq-to-object you can:

add a `.Where(p => p.IncomingPayments != null)` before chaining with your `.Select()` like this

```
o.Utilities.Where(p => p.IncomingPayments != null)
           .Select(p => p.IncomingPayments.Where(q => q.IncomingPaymentStatus == IncomingPaymentStatus.Pending || q.IncomingPaymentStatus == IncomingPaymentStatus.Processed))
```

The result will be a nested IEnumerable, i.e. `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IncomingUtilityPayment>>`

If you actually need a `IEnumerable<IncomingUtilityPayment>` then `.SelectMany()` come in to play.

```
o.Utilities.Where(p => p.IncomingPayments != null)
           .SelectMany(p => p.IncomingPayments)
           .Where(q => q.IncomingPaymentStatus == IncomingPaymentStatus.Pending || q.IncomingPaymentStatus == IncomingPaymentStatus.Processed)
```

Hope this help

Comment: I think this would solve my problem but when I use the code you provided I get the following error

The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path

Comment: It seems like SelectMany does not work in this situation.  It makes me use Select maybe because it is within an include statement.  If I do not have a where clause in the statement it works fine but as soon as I add the where I get the error list above

Comment: It seems like the Include() cannot contains a filtering (Where cause). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496681