# C# EF - Left join on a Included entity with a filter

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following Table Structure

```
Orders
 OrderID PK

PartyAddresses
 PartyAddressID PK
```

Then I have a join table that joins PartyAddress to a order

```
OrderAddresses
 OrderAddressID PK
 OrderID FK to Orders
 PartyAddressID FK to PartyAddresses
 AddressType
```

The sql statment I am trying to convert is

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
Orders o  LEFT JOIN OrdersAddresses oa
       ON 
    o.OrderID = oa.OrderID
       LEFT JOIN PartyAddresses pa
          ON
       pa.PartyAddressID = oa.PartyAddressID
WHERE
    oa.AddressType = 'SHIP'
```

I am having trouble figuring out to replicate this into Linq lambda statements

I have been been able to retrieve the data I want by starting at the OrdersAddress table

```
OrdersAddresses.Include("Orders").Include("PartyAddresses").Where(oa=>oa.AddressType=="Ship");
```

But I need the results in terms of a `IEnumerable<Orders>`

***Update***

I guess to rephrase my question - given the following repository function

```
public IQueryable<Orders> OrdersWithAddresses()
{
    return _context.Orders.Include("OrdersAddresses").Include("OrdersAddresses.PartyAddresses");
}
```

How would i add to the expression tree to only actually return order addresses that are "SHIP"

Comment: What is the point of the first left join when you filter on it anyway?

Comment: Clarified the source and why its using the left join

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF: Include with where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause)

Comment: I think the way to go would be the answer by Gert Arnold at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head but I believe it should work. Note that I've removed the first LEFT JOIN as it is just as easy to do a normal join due to the WHERE clause filtering out the NULLs anyway:

```
var results = from o in db.Orders
              join oa in db.OrdersAddresses on o.OrderID equals oa.OrderID
              join pa in db.PartyAddresses on oa.PartyAddressID equals pa.PartyAddressID into pas
              from p in pas.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where oa.AddressType == "SHIP"
              select new { o, oa, p };
```

Update:

Alternatively you can modify your repository function to include a Where clause:

```
public IQueryable<Orders> OrdersWithAddresses(Func<Orders, bool> predicate)
{
    var orders = _context.Orders.Include("OrdersAddresses").Include("OrdersAddresses.PartyAddresses");

    if(predicate != null)
        return orders.Where(predicate);

    return orders;
}
```

And call the function like this:

```
var orders = OrdersWithAddresses(o => o.AddressType = "SHIP");
```

Comment: Thanks , but I need the results as a populated Graph of Orders objects

Comment: Can you explain what that means?

Comment: Your solution would give me a list of anonymous objects that combine all 3 as separate properties. Instead why I need is a populated Orders object that I can drill down using navigation properties. Ex. results.First().OrderAddresses.First().PartyAddresses.City

Comment: all you need to do is update the last line then, something like `select new Order { ... };`

Comment: I don't think that would work because I don't need a NEW order - i need the order that was returned by EF ,including the change tracking etc...

Comment: Yeah that would work :-) , but what i am trying to figure out is, What would go into that Where predicate