# Entity Framework. Limited include query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an object `Customer` with a `one-to-many` relation to `Visit`.
The visits have certain `VisitType`.

I want to fetch only `Visits` after a certain date and this for all my `Customers`. Therefor i pass the parameter `referenceDate`

Linq query i can think of that would give me the desired result:

```
customers.Include(c => c.Visits.Where(v => v.VisitDate >= referenceDate)).ToList();
```

Offcourse this does not work since `Include` actually requires a path.

Is there a Linq alternative for this problem or should i write custom queries for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF: Include with where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause)

Comment: This is not a good solution. When performing the .Select(x => x.b) following error occurs:  Column addition failed for symbol type 'Devart.Common.Entity.ae' and current expression 'Devart.Common.Entity.ae'. I have other properties on my object that are causing these problems.

Comment: `customers.Select(c => new { c, Visits = c.Visits.Where(v => v.VisitDate >= referenceDate) }).AsEnumerable().Select(a => a.c).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like that:

```
customers.Include(c => c.Visits).Where(c => c.Visits.VisitDate >= referenceDate)).ToList();
```

or

`customers.Include("Visits").Where(c => c.Visits.VisitDate >= referenceDate)).ToList();`

Comment: This would exclude my Customers without visits.

Comment: Ah ok... And something like this? customers.Include(c => c.Visits).Where(c => c.Visits.VisitDate >= referenceDate || c => c.Visits == null || c.Visits.Count == 0 )).ToList(); I am not on my development machine now, so that code is not tested ;) Also i am pretty sure that Visits don't hast to be checked for null and count = 0. One of them should be enough...

Comment: this would still include all my visits, it's a filter on the customer