# Use Linq Where on child entity in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserProperty> Properties {get; set;}
}

public class UserProperty
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public int PropertyId {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
    public virtual Property Property {get; set;}
}

public class Property
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool IsActive {get; set;}
}
```

I have repository method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<User> Get(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<User, object>>[] include)
{
    var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<User, object>>, IQueryable<User>>
                (dbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

    return set.Where(predicate);
}
```

I'm trying to get a list of user properties where the properties' IsActive is true, so I'm doing:

```
public IEnumerable<UserProperty> GetSearches(int userId)
{
    return userRepository.Get(x => x.Id == userId, 
                              x => x.Properties.Where(p => p.Property.IsActive).Select(p => p.Property)).Properties;
}
```

However, I'm getting this exception:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The following alternative works:

```
return userRepository.Get(x => x.Id == userId,
                          x => x.Properties.Select(p => p.Property)).Properties.Where(p => p.Property.IsActive);
```

However, the where clause is not included in the SQL statement to the db but executed after all records have been retrieved.

I would like to limit the number of records retrieved directly in the db.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something simpler:

```
public IEnumerable<UserProperty> GetSearches(int userId)
{
    return userRepository.Where(x => x.Id == userId).Select(x => x.Properties.Where(p => p.IsActive)).Single(); //I assumed userId is unique
}
```

If you need to group more user's properties then use a [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I would like to use the repository method above. UserRepository is not IDbSet but a class that inherits from a generic repository.

Comment: Well then you should be able to get a table from the repo as IEnumerable or IQueryable.

Comment: `Select(p.Properties.Where(x => x.IsActive))` doesn't compile.