# Linq many to many include

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many

I have 3 entities

```cs
public class A
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}

public class AB
{
    public int AId { get; set; }

    public virtual A A { get; set; }

    public int BId { get; set; }

    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}
```

I need to write the following SQL in Linq :

```
SELECT * FROM A, AB
WHERE
A.Name = 'name'
AND AB.BId = 1
```

I've tried:

```
DbContext.Set<A>().Include(a => a.ABs.Select(ab => ab.B).Where(b => b.Id == 1)).Single(a => a.Name == "name");

DbContext.Set<A>().Include(a => a.ABs.Where(ab => ab.BId == 1)).Single(a => a.Name == "name");

DbContext.Set<A>().Include(a => a.ABs.Select(ab => ab.BId == 1).Single(a => a.Name == "name");

DbContext.Set<A>().Include(a => a.ABs.Any(ab => ab.BId == 1)).Single(a => a.Name == "name");
```

I always get the same message :

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

I'd like to understand the error message.

My questions :

- Is "public virtual ICollection ABs" a navigation property ?
- What are dotted paths ?
- What's the difference between "reference navigation properties" and "collection navigation properties" ?
- What should I change to get my request to work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is "public virtual ICollection ABs" a navigation property ?
>   What's the difference between "reference navigation properties" and "collection navigation properties" ?

Yes. A navigation property is a property by which you "navigate" from one entity to another. They come in two flavors. `A.ABs` is a *collection* navigation property, `AB.B` is a *reference* navigation property. The other properties, like `A.Name`, are called *scalar properties*.

> What are dotted paths ?

Paths with a dot in it. But the message isn't really clear here. It applies to included properties nested in other navigation properties.

So collection navigation properties are included by a `Select`:

```
DbContext.Set<A>().Include(a => a.AB.Select(ab => ab.Cees))
```

(where `Cees` is a collection in `AB`)

And reference navigation properties are included by dots:

```
DbContext.Set<A>().Include(a => a.D.F)
```

(where `D` and `F` are references)

But to me that's not clear at all, because...

```
Include(a => a.ABs.Select(ab => ab.B))
```

... includes a reference by a `Select`. Well, it's hard to conceive clear *and* brief exception messages.

> What should I change to get my request to work ?

The message is not too clear, but, worse, it doesn't tell what's wrong either. You *do* use navigation properties *defined on the type*!

```
Include(a => a.ABs.Select(ab => ab.B).Where(b => b.Id == 1))
```

But you can't have the `Where` in it. This is a notorious pitfall. The lambda syntax *suggests* that any LINQ method can be used in `Include`s, but in reality only `Select` and `.` are allowed to append navigation properties.

What you want is a often-requested feature: **filtered Include**. Presently, EF only supports including full collections. In EF 7, finally filtered `Include`s will be supported.

Until then, you have to use work-around, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801205/861716).

Answer (score 0):

```
var ww = _context.Agentes.Include(a => a.AgentesObjetos.Select(ab => ab.Objeto)).ToList();
```

error 
InvalidOperationException: The Include property lambda expression `a => {from AgenteObjeto ab in a.AgentesObjetos select [ab].Objeto}` is invalid.

The expression should represent a property access: `t => t.MyProperty`.

To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. `(Derived d) => d.MyProperty`.

For more information on this subject, including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.