# EF. How to include only some sub results in a model?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to select list of Users and for each User JobTitle in correct language depended of strLang selected by user.

Something like that:

```
IList<User> myData;
myData = Context.Users.Where(u => u.Location == strLocation)
                .Include(u => u.JobTitles.Where(e => e.Language == strLang))
                    .ToList();
```

But it seems Include doesn't like Where clause

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error message: "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path"

Comment: Would this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16801205/3279876

Comment: No as I don't want to create new model/object, I just want to reduce number of results

Comment: Try Include(u => u.JobTitles).Where(e => e.Language == strLang).ToList();

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work: "'User' does not contain definition for Language.

Comment: Is JobTitles a navigation property of Users? Can we see the Users and JobTitle classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't conditionally include only a few entities of a related collection, so you should use projection to get the stuff you need:

```
IList<User> myData;
var temp = Context.Users.Where(u => u.Location == strLocation)
      .Select(u => new
      {
        User = u;
        Locations = u.JobTitles.Where(e => e.Language == strLang));
      });

foreach(var t in temp)
{
   User user = t.User;
   user.Locations = t.Locations;
   myData.Add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it by using the "Include" method since it only take naviation properties.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project EF+ on github.

**EF+ Query IncludeFilter** allow you to easily filter related entities:

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.    
IList<User> myData;
    myData = Context.Users.Where(u => u.Location == strLocation)
                    .IncludeFilter(u => u.JobTitles.Where(e => e.Language == strLang))
                        .ToList();
```

You can find the project [here](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

You can find the documentation [here](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

Behind the code, IncludeFilter do exactly like Alexander answer by using a projection.