# Wire up ExpressionVisitor with EF Core Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an `ExpressionVisitor` which I add to EF Core's `IQueryable<T>`. Everything works fine except the Include methods. Probably because they enforce your `IQueryable<T>.Provider` to be an `EntityQueryProvider`.

Whenever I try to Include now it results in multiple queries which in turn results in the error "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.".

How can I wire up my `ExpressionVisitor` so it still works with EF Core's Include functionality?

My issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971376/modify-the-expression-tree-of-iqueryable-include-to-add-condition-to-the-join) except for EF Core instead of EF.

I hook up my `ExpressionVisitor` by calling it on the DbSet:

```
        return new Translator<TEntity>(
            _dbSet
                .AsNoTracking());
```

This is my `Translator` class:

```
public class Translator<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly Expression _expression;
    private readonly TranslatorProvider<T> _provider;

    public Translator(IQueryable source)
    {
        _expression = Expression.Constant(this);
        _provider = new TranslatorProvider<T>(source);
    }

    public Translator(IQueryable source, Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }

        _expression = expression;
        _provider = new TranslatorProvider<T>(source);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)_provider.ExecuteEnumerable(_expression)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _provider.ExecuteEnumerable(_expression).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Type ElementType => typeof(T);

    public Expression Expression => _expression;

    public IQueryProvider Provider => _provider;
}
```

And this is my `TranslatorProvider<T>` class (I've taken out the non-relevant Visit methods to shorten the post):

```
public class TranslatorProvider<T> : ExpressionVisitor, IQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryable _source;

    public TranslatorProvider(IQueryable source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        _source = source;
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }

        return new Translator<TElement>(_source, expression);
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }

        var elementType = expression.Type.GetGenericArguments().First();
        var result = (IQueryable) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Translator<>).MakeGenericType(elementType),
            _source, expression);
        return result;
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }

        var result = (this as IQueryProvider).Execute(expression);
        return (TResult) result;
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }

        var translated = Visit(expression);
        return _source.Provider.Execute(translated);
    }

    internal IEnumerable ExecuteEnumerable(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }

        var translated = Visit(expression);
        return _source.Provider.CreateQuery(translated);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type == typeof(Translator<T>))
        {
            return _source.Expression;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.VisitConstant(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 3.x):**

The internal query pipeline infrastructure has changed. The new query expression preprocessing extension point is [QueryTranslationPreprocessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.querytranslationpreprocessor?view=efcore-3.1) class - [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.querytranslationpreprocessor.process?view=efcore-3.1) method. Plugging it in requires replacing the [IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.iquerytranslationpreprocessorfactory?view=efcore-3.1). e.g.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
{
    public class CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessor : RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessor
    {
        public CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessor(QueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies dependencies, RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies relationalDependencies, QueryCompilationContext queryCompilationContext)
            : base(dependencies, relationalDependencies, queryCompilationContext) { }
        public override Expression Process(Expression query) => base.Process(Preprocess(query));
        private Expression Preprocess(Expression query)
        {
            // query = new YourExpressionVisitor().Visit(query);               
            return query;
        }
    }

    public class CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory : IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory
    {
        public CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory(QueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies dependencies, RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies relationalDependencies)
        {
            Dependencies = dependencies;
            RelationalDependencies = relationalDependencies;
        }
        protected QueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies Dependencies { get; }
        protected RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies RelationalDependencies;
        public QueryTranslationPreprocessor Create(QueryCompilationContext queryCompilationContext)
            => new CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessor(Dependencies, RelationalDependencies, queryCompilationContext);
    }
}
```

and

```
optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory, CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory>();
```

**Original:**

Apparently custom query providers don't fit in the current EF Core queryable pipeline, since several methods (`Include`, `AsNoTracking` etc.) require provider to be `EntityQueryProvider`.

At the time of writing (EF Core 2.1.2), the query translation process involves several services - `IAsyncQueryProvider`, `IQueryCompiler`, `IQueryModelGenerator` and more. All they are replaceable, but the easiest place for interception I see is the `IQueryModelGenerator` service - `ParseQuery` method.

So, forget about custom `IQueryable` / `IQueryProvider` implementation, use the following class and plug your expression visitor inside `Preprocess` method:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal;
using Remotion.Linq;
using Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionVisitors.TreeEvaluation;

class CustomQueryModelGenerator : QueryModelGenerator
{
    public CustomQueryModelGenerator(INodeTypeProviderFactory nodeTypeProviderFactory, IEvaluatableExpressionFilter evaluatableExpressionFilter, ICurrentDbContext currentDbContext)
        : base(nodeTypeProviderFactory, evaluatableExpressionFilter, currentDbContext)
    { }

    public override QueryModel ParseQuery(Expression query) => base.ParseQuery(Preprocess(query));

    private Expression Preprocess(Expression query)
    {
        // return new YourExpressionVisitor().Visit(query);               
        return query;
    }
}
```

and replace the corresponding EF Core service inside your derived context `OnConfiguring` override:

```
optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IQueryModelGenerator, CustomQueryModelGenerator>();
```

The drawback is that this is using EF Core "internal" stuff, so you should keep monitoring for changes in the future updates.

Comment: As usual, Ivan to the rescue. It requires a custom EF Core because I need to add code to the ExpressionEqualityComparer, but this is something I can live with.

Comment: `IQueryModelGenerator` does not appear to exist any more in EF Core 3.1. Does anyone have a good general purpose alternative for where to hook into the query pipeline?

Comment: @RyanThomas Post updated. There is also a similar factory/processor pair for postprocessing.