# Get data from normalized tables

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity

I would like to retrive data (list of channels for category).

Here's my model:

```
public class Category : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<CategoryChannel> CategoryChannels { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryChannel : Entity<int>
{
    [Display(Name = "Channel")]
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChannelId")]
    public virtual Channel Channel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Channel : AuditableEntity<string>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<CategoryChannel> CategoryChannels { get; set; } 
}
```

And here's my code for retrive data:

```
    return _entities.Set<Channel>()
        .Include(x => x.CategoryChannels).Where(y => y.Name.Equals(category))
        .AsEnumerable();
```

And finally I've got an error message:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'xxx.Channel' does not declare a navigation property
>   with the name 'CategoryChannels'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` can't be a navigation property used for lazy/eager loading, you'll have to use an implementation of `ICollection<T>` for that (Array, List, HashSet...) or just `ICollection<T>` itself of course.

`IEnumerable` is lazy by default because of [deferred execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx) which is why you need an implementation which ensures a local copy of the collection.

Comment: I've changed my code for List, but now I got empty list (supposed to be 2)

Comment: You kept the list virtual right? It might be possible EF expects your model to instantiate the List (not entirely sure on this). Try to add a constructor to `Channel`: `public Channel() { CategoryChannel = new List<CateGoryChannel>(); }`

Comment: Yeah, but I found another problem. I refared to Channel Name ("Where(y => y.Name.Equals(category))" but I should refer to Category Name

Comment: Conditionally eager loading related entities is not possible. You get them all or you get none, but that's another topic :)

Comment: Sure, but if I would like to Lazy Loading it is possible, but I'm looking for how can I do this

Comment: @Cieja It's not possible. This is a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34965741/3410196

Comment: Hmm, So how can retrieve Channels by category? I would like List of Channels as a result (not CategoryChannels list)

Comment: So you have a category already? `var channels = category.CategoryChannels.Select(c => c.Channel).ToList();`

Comment: But in this solution I have to create two queries. I have only category as a string, so I would like to retrieve channels by category which I have as a string in one query.

Comment: You have the category's primary key already, I think you can figure out yourself how to get the category. This site is for specific programming problems like your initial issue, not for writing your code.