# How To specify Where in Include in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, include, where-clause

I have faced this issue many times and I wanted to know the best approach to deal with Where clause in Include. Here is my sample code

```
IEnumerable<Data.StoreMenu> dataStoreMenus = _context.StoreMenus
                .Include(sm => sm.MenuCategories.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted))
                .Where(sm => sm.StoreId == storeId && !sm.IsDeleted).ToList();
```

The scenario is I have a menu and Menu has multiple menu categories. Both menu and menu categories has a flag to mark items deleted. Now I want to retrieve only non-deleted menu along with NON-DELETED menu categories.

Comment: You can do a join between the StoreMenus table and the MenuCategories where IsDeleted is false with .Join() method. I do not think what you want to achieve is possible within .Include().

Comment: Thanks... just wanted to find alternatives as you provided one to use join()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subquery:

```
var result = _context.StoreMenus
.Where(sm => sm.StoreID == storeId && !sm.IsDeleted)
.Select(sm=> 
   new { Menu=sm, MenuCats = sm.MenuCategories.Where(smc => !smc.IsDeleted) })
.ToList();
```

Might want to have a look at something similar: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause?rq=1)