# Linq Include with where predicate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

[image: db model schema]

I have this model in my DB, and specific classes to represent it in ef core.

I am using GenericRepository and trying to get a collection of DietProduct table which later would be adapted by auto mapper for a view.

The problem starts when I try to get the list of all active DietProducts with DietproductLocalization where LanguageId = @LanguageId;

I tried to complete a generic method like this:

```
public List<TEntity> FindComplex(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params string[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = Context.Set<TEntity>();

            foreach (var include in includes)
                query = query.Include(include);

            return query.Where(predicate).ToList();
        }
```

and then use the select as:

```
int currentLanguage = LanguageUtility.GetLanguageId(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var dp = _repo.DietProduct.FindComplex(x => x.Active 
                                            && x.DietProductLocalization
                                                 .Any(l => l.LanguageId == currentLanguage), "DietProductLocalization");
```

but no luck so far, because it keeps returning all the rows from included table, of course as include stands for [all or nothing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/10/12/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include/).

Is there any way to write the generic method and specific query so I don't have to use specific queries with inner  joins all over?

Comment: If you are using Auto Mapper you should take a look at the [QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) helper methods it has built in. It is designed to make your mappings work on IQueryable objects without pulling everything in to memory or needing to do manual joins like you are.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause) answer as you may find it helpful.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the response, but I was really hoping to get some ef-related solution

Comment: @CodingYoshi thanks for the response, yes I have seen that post, the problem with it is because I can't turn it into a generic.

Comment: EF itself has no solution as it is, so it means you'll have to filter in memory or resort to extension frameworks - you'd need to intersept EF query generating if you want to do it yourself DB-side, which is not a good idea IMO.

Comment: It's very simple. EF never gratified this often-requested feature. So now at least once a week there's a question along these lines at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro and GertArnold thanks for your effort anyway, It seems like we have to type the select queries manually, all of them :) 
The link I provided to my question on how to solve one case of these was since 2009, I was just thinking/hoping that someone solved it somehow. Cheers to everyone