# Filtering multi-level includes in EF

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following relationship between 3 tables

grandparent: Environment

parent: Organization

child: Dataset

I would like to select all Datasets
from the organization where OrganizationName == org
and the environment where EnvironmentName == env

I try with Entity Framework this

```
   var result = myContext.Environment
                                .Where(t => t.EnvironmentName == env)
                                .Include(s => s.Organizations)
                                .Where(t => t.OrganizationName == org)
                                .Include(t => t.Datasets);
```

but it does not work - the error message says that t.OrganizationName is not a member of Environment - and this is true

OrganizationName and EnvironmentName are unique

How can this be done?

Comment: [`Include`s can't be filtered.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801205/861716)

Comment: what is the relationships between the entities ? is it one to one ??? if you need Datasets then dont you  think you need to queryover  Datasets entity ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the dataset with this query:

```
var dataSets = from ds in myContext.Dataset
               join o in myContext.Organization on ds.OrganizationId equals o.OrganizationId
               join e in myContext.Environment on o.EnvironmentId equals e.EnvironmentId
               where e.EnvironmentName == "TEST"
               where o.OrganizationName == "TSO"
               select ds;
```

Comment: In SQL I would like to do this

SELECT d.*
FROM dbo.Environment AS e INNER JOIN

     dbo.Organization AS o ON e.EnvironmentId = o.EnvironmentId INNER JOIN
     dbo.Dataset AS d 
ON o.OrganizationId = d.OrganizationId
WHERE e.EnvironmentName = 'TEST' and o.OrganizationName = 'TSO'

Comment: @PaulSorensen I edited my anwser according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

EF+ Query IncludeFilter feature allows filtering related entities.

```
var result = myContext.Environment
            .Where(t => t.EnvironmentName == env)
            .IncludeFilter(s => s.Organizations.Where(o => OrganizationName == org))
            .IncludeFilter(t => t.Datasets);
```

Note: You cannot mixte Include && IncludeFilter.