# EF include with where clause db first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am aware of the other similar question at the link below, but those answers do not work as I am db first and the entity framework plus solution is very slow and appears to just get every record and filter it out afterwards.
[EF: Include with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause)

drivers and passengers are navigational properties on busses. preferredBrands is a `List<String>`. So basically what I want is all busses where typeid = 2, all drivers where their preferredbrand is listed in the preferredbrand list, and all passengers. The query below throws exception:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
>   Parameter name: path

Query:

```
var result =  db.busses.Where(h => h.bussesTypeId.Equals(2))
.Include(h => h.drivers.Where(p => preferredBrands.Contains(p.PreferredBrand)))
.Include(h => h.passengers).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

'Include' only accepts string parameter and not delegate. You have to place the Relational property in quote (string). Do this instead

```
var result =  db.busses
.Include("drivers.preferredBrands")
.Include("passengers")
.Where(h => h.bussesTypeId.Equals(2));
```

To access drivers, use

```
result.drivers.where(p => preferredBrands.Contains(p.PrefferedBrand));
```

However, if you must use delegate in your include, then 
1. Reference Z.EntityFramework from Nuget
2. Then you can use 'IncludeFilter' instead as follows;

```
  using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;

  var result =  db.busses
  .IncludeFilter(h => h.drivers.Where(p => preferredBrands.Contains(p.PrefferedBrand)))
  .IncludeFilter(h => h.passengers)
  .Where(h => h.bussesTypeId.Equals(2)).ToList();
```

Note: You must use the Include or IncludeFilter before the where clause. It must be used directly on the EF Entity and not just on any IEnumerable