# Entity Framework Query - how to return desired results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have this query

```
ViewBag.Tags = db.Tag_Group
   .Where(u => 
      u.Tags.Any(d => d.CategoryName.Contains("|" + CategoryID + "|")) 
      & u.Tags.Any(s=>s.Tag_List.Any(d=>d.Item.ItemsOnStock>0)))
   .OrderBy(y => y.TagGrupName)
   .ToList();
```

It returns all groups and not only `ItemsOnStock>0` groups.

What am I doing wrong ?

`Tag_List` has many `Item` and many `Tags`. `Tag_Group` has many `Tags`

Table `Tag_List` is used to store `Tags` for specific `Items`.

I only need `List<Tag_Group>` for items that are on stock. Is there some better way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the SQL Statement that this gets turned into and running it yourself against the database? This EF query looks fine to me and I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Change Any to Where. Maybe this is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a disguised "filtered Include" question and the answer is similar to the usual [work-around for lack of filtering in `Include`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801205/861716).

In your case, you better start the query at the `Tags` and group them by their `TagGroup` (of which I assume the navigation property exists):

```
db.Tags
  .Where(t => t.CategoryName.Contains("|" + CategoryID + "|") 
           && t.Tag_List.Any(d => d.Item.ItemsOnStock > 0))
  .GroupBy(t => t.TagGroup)
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(g => g.Key)
  .OrderBy(y => y.TagGroupName)
  .ToList();
```

Remember to disable lazy loading, so the groups' `Tags` collections won't be populated fully when you access them.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you get the wrong result because of your one `&` instead of `&&`?

So you have a class `Tag_Group`. Every object of `Tag_Group` has zero or more `Tags`.

Every `Tag` has a string `CategoryName` and an IEnumerable `Tag_List` that contains zero or more `Items`. Every `Item` has an int(?) property `ItemOnStock`. The `int` part is not important. It can be any class as long as you can compare it with zero.

It seems you want all `Tag_Group` objects that have at least one `Tag` in its sequence of `Tags` that:

- Has a `CategoryName` equal to "|" + CategoryID + "|"
- **AND** has at least one item in `Tag_List` that has an `ItemOnStock > 0`

Or could it be that you want all `Tag_Group` objects that

- Has at least one `Tag` in `Tags` with a `CategoryName` equal to "|" + CategoryID + "|"
- **OR** has at least one `Tag` in `Tags` that has at leas one item in `Tag_List` that has an `ItemOnStock > 0`. This `Tag` may be a different `Tag` than the one with the `CategoryName`

I assume you want the AND option.

Although you didn't say so, I assume db is your dbContext, and you want your query to be performed by the database, so AsQueryable, and not AsEnumerable.

```
var CategoryId = ...
string categoryName = "|" + CategoryId + "|";

var result = db.Tag_Group
   // I want only those tagGroupElements that have at least one Tag
   // in sequence Tags that matches both conditions:
   .Where(tagGroupElement => tagGroupEleent.Tags
             // the tagGroupElement should have a matching CategoryName
       .Where(tag => tag.CategoryName == categoryName)
             // and the tagGroupElement should have at least one item
             // in Tag_List with ItemOnStock > 0
          && tag.Tag_List
              .Where(tagListElement => tagListElement.ItemOnStock > 0)
              .Any())
       .Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your help :)

I ended up using a bit modified Gert's answer since I needed Tags grouped by TagGroup

```
db.Tags
  .Where(t => t.CategoryName.Contains("|" + CategoryID + "|") 
           && t.Tag_List.Any(d => d.Item.ItemsOnStock > 0))
  .GroupBy(t => t.TagGroup.GroupName)
  .OrderBy(y => y.Key)
  .ToList();
```

I learned a lot from your answers