# Entity Framework LINQ query to return a list and subset of collection satisfying certain condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an entity `TimesheetHeader` which has a `User` object, and start date and end date corresponding to the week of timesheet entry, and an `ICollection` of `TimesheetEntry`.

`TimesheetEntry` is another entity which contains a `Project` entity, date and hours object (each `TimesheetEntry` basically records the number of hours the user worked on a project on a day).

I have to generate a report to find out the various users and breakdown of hours worked on each day on a particular project.

Currently my logic is to first get a list as follows:

```
context.TimesheetHeader.Where(u => u.status.statusName != "deleted" && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(u.StartDate) >= dateStart && u.TimesheetEntry.Any(te => te.projectId == report.project)).ToList();
```

But this basically returns a `TimesheetHeader` and all its `TimesheetEntry` if there is at least one `TimesheetEntry` corresponding to the project.

Then I have to loop and filter the result.

Is there a better solution to this where I can directly get the result from the query itself, where I get the `TimesheetHeader` and only the subset of relevant `TimesheetEntry` corresponding to the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? I also suggest pluralizing your collections so it's more clear which end of the relationship you're on.

`context.TimesheetHeaders
    .Where(u => u.status.statusName != "deleted")
    .Where(u => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(u.StartDate) >= dateStart)
    .Where(u => u.TimesheetEntries.Any(te => te.projectId == report.project))
    .Select(u => new { 
        TimeSheetHeader = u, 
        TimeSheetHeaderEntries = u.TimesheetEntries.Where(te => te.projectId == report.project)
    })`

Comment: The problem is that, with the existing design of the application, the user details are in `TimesheetHeader` and project and date details are in `TimesheetEntry`.

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled or are you looking to get all the information at once?

Comment: I would rather get all the required data in a single query. Is that not better from a performance perspective?

Answer (score 1):

As Gert Arnold answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause)

you can try as below by adding where clause to your include :

```
context.TimesheetHeader.Where(u => u.status.statusName != "deleted" && 
 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(u.StartDate) >= dateStart).Select(t => { t, TimesheetEntries = t.TimesheetEntry.Where(te => te.projectId == report.project)).AsEnumerable()
 .Select(x => x.t)
 .ToList();
```

Or look at [EntityFramework-Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-IncludeFilter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Include-Related-Entities-using-Where-Filter). It might be useful.

Comment: Do I need to add this line: `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: The result with Lazy loading has `TimesheetEntry` of other projects as well.

Comment: If I disable Lazy loading, there are entries which does not contain any `TimesheetHeader`, how do I filter those out. I tried a Where Clause before the final select, but the result remained the same

Comment: Yes, that will work if lazy loading is disabled. Doesn't that return "TimesheetHeader and only the subset of relevant TimesheetEntry corresponding to the project"?

Comment: It returns all `TimesheetHeader` that satisfies the conditions in the initial query, with `TimesheetEntry` either null or those that match the project

Comment: In that case I think you can add condition in where clause as you did in code you posted, u.TimesheetEntry.Any(te => te.projectId == report.project) before selecting.