# Include Path Expression Must Refer To A Navigation Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I've search a lot about my problem but I didn't find any clear solution. I just know that I can't use Where linq clause with Include but it doesn't make sense to me that how I make this query.

```
var brands = await _context.Brands
            .Include(x => x.FoodCategories
                .Select(y => y.Products
                    .Where(z => z.Sugar)
                    .Select(w => w.FileDetail)))
            .ToListAsync();
```

Actually I want to apply the Where statement on Products but I want entities in hierarchy like I do here. How can I do it? 
I've already try myself with different stackoverflow question [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801205/9687763) but I'm not getting the point. Here is my trial:

```
var brands = _context.Brands
            .Select(b => new
            {
                b,
                FoodCategories = b.FoodCategories
                    .Where(x => x.BrandId == b.BrandId)
                    .Select(c => new
                    {
                        c,
                        Products = c.Products
                            .Where(y => y.FoodCategoryId == c.FoodCategoryId &&
                                        y.Sugar)
                            .Select(p => new
                            {
                                p,
                                File = p.FileDetail
                            })
                    })
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(z => z.b)
            .ToList();
```

But it is not returning all the product items instead of sugar only products.

Comment: I think you must use SelectMany to select detail of entities.

Comment: You cannot use `Where` statements in includes. Include statements are based on the **structure** of the entities, whereas a `Where` only filters **data** from a set. One has nothing to do with the other. And even though you'd think it'd be nice to do something like "include the parent only if they meet these criteria", that's simply not how `Include` was designed to work. Include boils down to  "for every [type1], also load their related [type2]". This will be done for _every_ [type1] object that your query will instantiate and it will load _every_ related [type2].

Comment: You are missing the following part from the linked answer - *"This only works when lazy loading is disabled. "* The screenshot you've posted under the current answer clearly indicates that **lazy loading** is active, which negates all your efforts.

Comment: @IvanStoev You're the beauty, Now everything is working fine. Can you please edit the answer of Flater. I'll mark it answer of my question.

Answer (score 0):

### **Why you're only getting sugar products**.

> But it is not returning all the product items instead of sugar only products.

Of course it is. Because you're asking it to only give you the sugar products:

```
var brands = _context.Brands
            .Select(b => new
            {
                b,
                FoodCategories = b.FoodCategories
                    .Where(x => x.BrandId == b.BrandId)
                    .Select(c => new
                    {
                        c,
                        Products = c.Products
                            .Where(y => y.FoodCategoryId == c.FoodCategoryId 
                                        && y.Sugar)                           //HERE!
                            .Select(p => new
                            {
                                p,
                                File = p.FileDetail
                            })
                    })
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(z => z.b)
            .ToList();
```

If you want all products; then don't filter on only the ones where `Sugar` is set to true.

---

There is a lot of redundant code here.

```
b.FoodCategories.Where(x => x.BrandId == b.BrandId)
```

`b.FoodCategories` already expresses the food categories of this particular brand `b`. You don't need the `Where`.

The same applies to

```
c.Products.Where(y => y.FoodCategoryId == c.FoodCategoryId ... )
```

---

Here's an improved version of your (second) snippet:

```
var brands = _context.Brands
            .Select(b => new
            {
                b,
                FoodCategories = b.FoodCategories
                    .Select(c => new
                    {
                        c,
                        Products = c.Products
                            .Select(p => new
                            {
                                p,
                                File = p.FileDetail
                            })
                    })
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(z => z.b)
            .ToList();
```

This should make it clearer that the custom `Select` logic isn't necessary. All you're doing is loading the related entities into properties of the same name. You can simply rely on the existing entities and their relations, there's no reason to define the same relationship again.

The only reason a custom `Select` would be desirable here was if:

- You wanted to limit the retrieved columns in order to lower the data size (useful for large queries)
- You want to selectively load children, not just all related children. Your code suggest that you want this, but then you say *"But it is not returning all the product items"* so I conclude that you don't want to filter the products on their sugar content.

---

### **Why your `Include` didn't work**.

SImply put: you cannot use `Where` statements in includes.

`Include` statements are based on the **structure** of the entities, whereas a `Where` only filters **data** from a set. One has nothing to do with the other.

And even though you'd think it'd be nice to do something like "include the parent only if they have an active status", that's simply not how `Include` was designed to work.
`Include` boils down to *"for every [type1], also load their related [type2]*". This will be done for **every** [type1] object that your query will instantiate and it will load **every** related [type2].

Taking the next step in refactoring the above snippet:

```
var brands = _context.Brands
                    .Include(b => b.FoodCategories)
                    .Include(b => b.FoodCategories.Select(fc => fc.Products))
                    .Include(b => b.FoodCategories.Select(fc => fc.Products.Select(p => p.FileDetail)))
                    .ToList();
```

The includes give Entity Framework specific instructions:

> - For every loaded brand, load its related food categories.
> - For every loaded food category, load its related products.
> - For every loaded product, load its related file details.

Notice that **it does not instruct WHICH brands should be loaded**! This is an important distinction to make. The `Include` statements do not in any way filter the data, they only explain what additional data needs to be retrieved for every entry that will be loaded.
*Which* entries will be loaded has not been defined yet. By default, you get the whole dataset, but you can apply further filtering using `Where` statements before you load the data.

> Think of it this way:
>
> A restaurant wants every new customer's mother to give permission to serve dessert to the customer. Therefore, the restaurant drafts a rule: "every customer must bring their mother".
>   This is the equivalent of `db.Customers.Include(c => c.Mother)`.
>
> This does not state **which** customers are allowed to visit the restaurant. It only states that **any** customer that visits the restaurant must bring their mother (if they have no mother, they will bring `null` instead).
>
> Notice how this rule applies regardless of which customers visit the restaurant:
>
> - Ladies night: `db.Customers.Include(c => c.Mother).Where(c => c.IsFemale)`
> - Parents night: `db.Customers.Include(c => c.Mother).Where(c => c.Children.Any())`
> - People whose father is named Bob night: `db.Customers.Include(c => c.Mother).Where(c => c.Father.Name == "Bob")`

Take note of the third example. Even though you filter on the father, you will only load the mother entity. It's perfectly possible to filter items on related entity values without actually loading the entities themselves (fathers).

---

You may ask yourself "why `Select`?". That's a good question, because it's not intuitive here.

Ideally, you'd want to do something like

```
context.Brand.Include(b => b.FoodCategories.Products.FileDetails)
```

But this is not possible because of a limitation in the language. `FoodCategories` is a `List<FoodCategory>`, which does not have a `Products` property.

However, `FoodCategory` itself *does* have a `Products` property. This is why `Select` is used: it allows you to access the properties of the list element's type, rather than the list itself.
Internally, EF is going to deconstruct your `Select` statement (which is an `Expression`) and it will figure out which property you want to be loaded. Don't worry too much about how EF works behind the scenes. It's not always pretty.

---

The Include/Select syntax is not the prettiest. Especially when you drill down multiple levels, it becomes cumbersome to write (and read).

So I suggest you **invert** your approach (start at the lowest child, drill up to the parent). Technically, it yields the same result, but it allows for a neater `Include` syntax:

```
var brands = context.FileDetails
                    .Include(fd => fd.Product)
                    .Include(fd => fd.Product.FoodCategory)
                    .Include(fd => fd.Product.FoodCategory.Brand)
                    .Select(fd => fd.Product.FoodCategory.Brand)
```

Now you don't need any nasty `Select` workaround in order to reference the related types.

Do note that you need to put an `Include` for every step! You can't just use the last `Include` and skip the others. EF does not infer that it needs to load multiple relations from a single `Include`.

Note that this trick only really works if you have a chain of one-to-many relationships. Many-to-many relationships make it harder to apply this trick. At worst, you'll have to resort to using the `Select` syntax from the earlier example.

---

While I am not a fan of the `Include` methods that take a string parameter (I don't like hardcoded strings that can fail on typos), I do feel it's relevant to mention here that they do not suffer from this issue. If you use the string-based includes, you can do things like:

```
context.Brands
         .Include("FoodCategories")
         .Include("FoodCategories.Products")
         .Include("FoodCategories.Products.FileDetails")
```

The parsing logic of the string include method will automatically look for the element inside the `List`, thereby effectively preventing the ugly syntax.

But there are other reasons why I generally don't advise using string parameters here (doesn't update when you rename a property, no intellisense, very prone to developer error)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Yes, it is some unbelievable happening there. Take a look on these screenshots.
Code: https://prntscr.com/jtkyhv Watch Window: https://prnt.sc/jtkzka https://prnt.sc/jtkzru