# Dotnet Core Entity Framework - ThenInclude with where

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Lets say you have the following entity realtionship

```
School ||---|< Course >|--|< Student
```

Worst drawing ever, but a *school* can have several *courses*, and a *course* can have several *students*.

In EF I would normally do it like this to get all the data:

```
return _db.School
       .Include(t => t.Classes)
       .ThenInclude(c => c.Course)
       .ThenInclude(s => s.Student)
```

But let say I only want students with name *Billy*.
Then I would guess I could to it like this

```
return _db.School
           .Include(t => t.Classes)
           .ThenInclude(o => o.Course)
           .ThenInclude(o => o.Student.Where(s => s.Studen.name.Equals( "Billy"))
```

Not possible as far as I can see, so therefore I do it like this:

```
return _db.School
     .Select(school => new School()
           {
               Id = school.Id
               Name = school.Name
               Courses = school.Courses.Select(courses => new Course() 
                    {
                       Id = course.Id,
                       Name = course.Name
                       Students = course.Students.Select(student => new Student()
                           {
                               Id = student.Id,
                               Name = student.Name
                           }).Where(s => s.Name.Equals("Billy"));
                     })
               });
etc....
```

**There must be a better way? Any suggestions?**

The code is just mocked, so might be a bunch of syntax errors and typos. But you get the idea.

Comment: What is the expected aggregate you want to see? Select all students where name is "Billy" or select schools with courses where any Billy is involved, or what is expected result?

Comment: Filtered `Include` is not supported. Try global query filters.

Comment: thanks for response, got the answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause