# Is there a way to Filter records when retrieve from EF Include Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to extract a record from TblRequisitionMaster(Parent Table) and `isActive==true` Records from TblRequestionDetail (Child Table).
Your guidance will be highly appreciated...

I am using .NET Core 3.1 & EF CORE. I need Entity Framework core work-around, not Third-party tools work-around like EF+.

This is my repository function.

```
public TblRequisitionMaster GetRequisitionMaster(int reqNo, byte companyId)
        {
            Company_CHLContext context = new Company_CHLContext(companyId);
            return context.TblRequisitionMaster.Include(i => i.TblRequestionDetail).SingleOrDefault(s => s.RequestionNo == reqNo && s.RecordStatus.Equals("AC") );
            
        }
```

Class Detail

```
public partial class TblRequisitionMaster
    {
        public TblRequisitionMaster()
        {
            TblRequestionDetail = new HashSet<TblRequestionDetail>();
        }

        public int RequestionNo { get; set; }
        public string ReqNo { get; set; }
        

        public virtual ICollection<TblRequestionDetail> TblRequestionDetail { get; set; }
    }

public partial class TblRequestionDetail
    {
        public int RequestionNo { get; set; }
        public byte SequenceNo { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual TblRequisitionMaster RequestionNoNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean just when you want to include it? or a global filter?

Comment: Duplicate: [EF: Include with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause). Please check if questions have been asked before. This issue keeps coming back.

Comment: @Gert, I had gone through this article but couldn't find an exact solution for ef core rather than a good suggestion. I would go following the direction if I knew about IgnoreQueryFilters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include filters are available only starting from EF Core 5

But you can specify [Query Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) which should start filtering includes automatically.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TblRequestionDetail>().HasQueryFilter(d => d.Active == true);
```

If you need to retrieve not filtered entities: apply [IgnoreQueryFilters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#disabling-filters) operator.

Comment: appreciate your prompt response. But if I edit model builder as suggested how to retrieve active==false records. Because some functions need only active records but sometimes we need to retrieve all records.

Comment: I think HasQueryFilter is just for root. it wont affect on child

Comment: QueryFilter affects all entities of specific type: root, navigation, FromSql - everything.