# LINQ Include with a Group By and new Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

Given the below query

```
var query = from vehicle in _context.Vehicle.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId && x.IsActive)

        //Left Outer to BookingVehicle. Used for subsequent Left Outers to Bookings
        join bookingVehicle in _context.BookingVehicle
            on vehicle.Id equals bookingVehicle.VehicleId
            into vehicle_bookingVehicle
        from bv in vehicle_bookingVehicle.DefaultIfEmpty()

        //Left Outer to Booking, for specific statuses. To get count of work-in-progress bookings
        join bookingActive in _context.Booking.Where(x => new[] { 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 13 }.Contains(x.StatusId))
            on bv.BookingId equals bookingActive.Id
            into bookingVehicle_bookingActive
        from ba in bookingVehicle_bookingActive.DefaultIfEmpty()

        //Left Outer to Booking. To get count of all bookings (irrespective of status), and date of latest booking
        join bookingHistory in _context.Booking
            on bv.BookingId equals bookingHistory.Id
            into bookingVehicle_bookingHistory
        from bh in bookingVehicle_bookingHistory.DefaultIfEmpty()

        group new { vehicle, ba, bh }
        by new { 
            Vehicle = vehicle
        }
        into grp

        select new VehicleItemListDTO
        {
            Vehicle = grp.Key.Vehicle,

            HasBookings = (grp.Count(g => g.ba.Id != null) > 0),
            HasHadBookings = (grp.Count(g => g.bh.Id != null) > 0),
            LastBooking = (grp.Max(g => g.bh.ScheduleStartUtc) != null) ? grp.Max(g => g.bh.ScheduleStartUtc) : grp.Max(g => g.bh.ActualStartUtc),
        };


var results = query.OrderBy(x => x.Vehicle.Id).ToList();

return results;
```

I have a custom object, VehicleItemListDTO, that includes a Domain Object of Vehicle, and some other parameters on how that vehicle is being used.

This is working fine.
However, I would like to include additional data about the Vehicle.
Some Vehicles have an assigned VehicleModel.

If I use an Include(y => y.VehicleModel) on the initial FROM statement, then the VehicleModel is not included in the data returned to the caller.
(With SQL Profiler, you can see the Left Join, but it is in a nested query, and subsequently lost).

I also tried:

```
var results = query.Include(z => z.Vehicle.VehicleMake).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

But that then errors at runtime with:

> The result type of the query is neither an EntityType nor a CollectionType with an entity element type. An Include path can only be specified for a query with one of these result types.

How can I get my Vehicle's VehicleModel **Include**d to the caller?

Comment: The error happens because you are calling include after the query.

Comment: If this is EF6 (for .net framework) then Include is always ignored when the query ends in a projection.

Comment: @GertArnold - is there a way or 'trick' to include it?

Comment: Does Vehicle has it's own DTO?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - Vehicle is a Domain Object. My custom DTO has several parameters, one of them being 'vehicle' which is a Vehicle Domain Object.

Comment: A work-around is [possible but quite elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801205/861716). Another thing is that you really should start using navigation properties instead of these verbose joins.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `include` before the query

```
var query = from vehicle in _context.Vehicle.Include(z => z.Vehicle.VehicleMake).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Id).Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId && x.IsActive)

...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as stated in the original post, this data gets discarded. According to SQL Profiler this data is in a nest query, and is not returned on the outer query. EF does not then have the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. I have changed grouping because it is not natural for the SQL to group by whole record

```cs
var groupingQuery = 
    from vehicle in _context.Vehicle.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId && x.IsActive)

    //Left Outer to BookingVehicle. Used for subsequent Left Outers to Bookings
    join bookingVehicle in _context.BookingVehicle
        on vehicle.Id equals bookingVehicle.VehicleId
        into vehicle_bookingVehicle
    from bv in vehicle_bookingVehicle.DefaultIfEmpty()

    //Left Outer to Booking, for specific statuses. To get count of work-in-progress bookings
    join bookingActive in _context.Booking.Where(x => new[] { 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 13 }.Contains(x.StatusId))
        on bv.BookingId equals bookingActive.Id
        into bookingVehicle_bookingActive
    from ba in bookingVehicle_bookingActive.DefaultIfEmpty()

    //Left Outer to Booking. To get count of all bookings (irrespective of status), and date of latest booking
    join bookingHistory in _context.Booking
        on bv.BookingId equals bookingHistory.Id
        into bookingVehicle_bookingHistory
    from bh in bookingVehicle_bookingHistory.DefaultIfEmpty()

    group new { ba, bh } by new { VehicleId = vehicle.Id } into grp

    select new 
    {
        VehicleId = grp.Key.VehicleId,

        HasBookings = (grp.Count(g => g.ba.Id != null) > 0),
        HasHadBookings = (grp.Count(g => g.bh.Id != null) > 0),
        LastBooking = grp.Max(g => g.bh.ScheduleStartUtc) ?? grp.Max(g => g.bh.ActualStartUtc),
    };

var query = 
    from g in groupingQuery
    join vehicle in _context.Vehicle on g.VehicleId equals vehicle.Id
    select new VehicleItemListDTO
    {
        Vehicle = new Vehicle
        {
            Id = vehicle.Id,
            ... // other fields
            VehicleMake = vehicle.VehicleMake
        },

        HasBookings = g.HasBookings,
        HasHadBookings = g.HasHadBookings,
        LastBooking = g.LastBooking,
    };

var results = query.OrderBy(x => x.Vehicle.Id).ToList();

return results;
```

We have to construct `Vehicle` object again to make `VehicleMake` initialized.

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately it does not work. It has the same result as original - the VehicleModel/VehicleMake objects are not included back to the Caller. Even through the Include statement is there, on SQL profiler I can see that they are not - EF is being too "smart" and saying that you dont need it, so it wont Get it.

Comment: Well, corrected answer. It should work.

Comment: Nope, no joy: System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'Models.Vehicle' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'.

Comment: Try also `VehicleMake  = new VehicleMake { ... }`. Not familiar with EF6 translator, for EF Core this is usual query.